# Running eXist-db XQuery in Saxon

Tags: xslt, saxon, exist-db

What is the recommended way in Saxon to load in an XML document from eXist-db via XQuery GET/POST within an XSL stylesheet?  I want to run an XQL query in eXist-db, which should be simple enough to do as a GET with `<xsl:variable name="test" select="doc('xmldb:exist:///db/test.xql')"/>` or `<xsl:variable name="test" select="doc('http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/test.xql')"/>`.  But the former doesn't exectute the query and tries to return the XQL source as XML, and the latter doesn't have the basic authentication to execute.  Also, I really want to send an XML fragment using POST, and have the XQL use that posted XML fragment.

I can't find anything in the Saxon documentation about this.  I did find an old EXPath article at http://expath.org/modules/http-client/samples, but the downloads there are 7 years old, and may not work with modern Saxon.  So looking for the best known method to do this.

Comment: Not sure what your usecase is and probably a lot of overkill, but take a look at xslweb. It also supports post and much more. It uses Saxon internally. I use it for web development when your main source is xml. github: https://github.com/Armatiek/xslweb ; presentation on xmlprague: https://archive.xmlprague.cz/2020/files/presentations/xslweb.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is the EXPath [HTTP Client](http://expath.org/modules/http-client/) module. There's no way to persuade the `doc()` or `document()` functions to do POST instead of GET, AFAIK.

Comment: Well, you can persuade the doc() function to do pretty well anything if you provide a custom resolver; but a user-written extension function probably makes more sense.

Comment: OK, so no POST without writing extensions in Java or C#, and nobody else has already done this, apart from EXPath HTTP Client.  Michael, this something I can/should be using with the latest Saxon?

Comment: On the GET, what about simply using doc() to execute XQuery in eXist-db via GET?  Is that possible?  xmldb:exist always returns the XQuery source rather than the query results.  And the REST url fails as I can't pass the basic auth username:password.  Am I missing the way to do this, or does it simply not work?

Comment: If you change the permissions on the query stored in eXist, so that it is executable by guest, you will not need to worry about authentication.

Comment: Thanks Joe.  That got doc('http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/test.xql') working for me as a GET.  Curious, am I correct to assume doc('xmldb:exist:///db/test.xql') cannot execute the query and can only return source?

Comment: Yes you are correct, doc('xmldb:exist:///db/test.xql') cannot execute the query and can only return source.